# Spring Boot Gradle - could not resolve all artifacts for configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am having an issue with one of my local builds. I used the spring initializer to generate a demo gradle project. Executing `gradle bootRun` leads to the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE.
         > Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom
            > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:2.1.6.RELEASE.
               > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:2.1.6.RELEASE.
                  > Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:2.1.6.RELEASE.
                        > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:2.1.6.RELEASE.
                           > Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-parent-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom
                              > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.6.RELEASE.
                                 > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.6.RELEASE.
                                    > Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom
                                       > Could not resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Lovelace-SR9.
                                          > Could not resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Lovelace-SR9.
                                             > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Lovelace-SR9/spring-data-releasetrain-Lovelace-SR9.pom'.
                                                > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Lovelace-SR9/spring-data-releasetrain-Lovelace-SR9.pom?referrer'.
                                                   > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

It seems to only be an issue with the standard release, not snapshots.

Comment: It looks like your JVM could not establish a chain of trust for `repo.jfrog.org`'s SSL certificate. That could be a problem at JFrog's end or, more likely, a problem with your Java installation. What version of Java are you running the build with?

Comment: The most likely cause for the problem is: you are in a corporate network; you are using an https proxy; and Java doesn't recognize the certificate of your https proxy. There are related answers on SO about this - you need to retrieve the certificate (export it using a web browser); and install the certificate in the certificate store for your Java installation

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade the gradle version and currently upgrade to Gradle 5.5.1 is ok

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot